# CRON jobs keep erroring

Tags: php, linux, apache, cron

We have several CRON jobs running on our apache / whm server. We are using php. The scripts all work completely fine when run from the browser.

The cron will throw back errors like: unable to include files (even when giving the absolute path).

Results will also vary, corrupting output files etc. I am really baffled, as sometimes the crons work fine as well. Seems really intermittent and they work every time perfectly when executed from the browser.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: What account are the cron jobs running under? Unable to include absolute-pathed files usually indications a permissions problem.

Comment: I suggest you debug your PHP cron jobs from the command-line. The CLI environment is completely different from HTTP.

Comment: @Marc B - I think you might be on to something there. Bit weird that the work "sometimes" but will have a look. Maybe set the cron up on the root crontab??

Comment: Running a script under a root crontab can be quite dangerous. I'd advise NOT doing so.

Comment: PHP CLI may have a distinct ".ini" file in your distro, if so check memory_limit and other parameters to see if they match the php.ini used by apache or force scripts to use the same "php.ini" file.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has pointed out, PHP CLI and the PHP Apache Module are separate software and they have separate configuration files.

Rather than set the crontab up on the root cron tab, make sure all your permissions are correct. Debug with the user they will run from cron as. Assuming you are running Linux, you can use

```
sudo -i -u username
```

for this.